# Bizmonade - testing orchestration that receives ANY document

Tags: tdd, biztalk, orchestration

I have an orchestration that receives any document type in BizTalk (System.Xml.Document). It looks like Bizmonade always wants to use an orchestration that specifies a type of schema that is different from ANY.

```
OrchestrationSimulator.Test<Dummy__Simulated>()
.When(MessageReceived.FromFile<CanonicalInvoice>(
 Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"Test.Files\CanonicalInvoice.xml")))
.ExpectCompleted<Dummy__Simulated>()
.ExecuteTest();
```

Any thoughts how to make it work with something similar to:

```
OrchestrationSimulator.Test<Dummy__Simulated>()
.When(MessageReceived.FromFile<XmlDocument__Simulated>( // or not to specify at all?
 Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"Test.Files\CanonicalInvoice.xml")))
.ExpectCompleted<Dummy__Simulated>() 
.ExecuteTest();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 1.0.0.2 (just released) should be able to do it.